DIY pulse oximeter circuit - phototransistor shows no reading
I am trying to do a project using Raspberry Pi Pico H, that will work as a pulse oximeter. I have designed the circuit in the image (note: the exact pins on the photo might not match with the code because I have changed it several times, but trust me the pins in the code are what I have connected right now), and connected it, but when I tried a simple program to read raw input from the phototransistor:
from machine import Pin, ADC, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
import time

red_led = Pin(21, Pin.OUT)     
ir_led = Pin(20, Pin.OUT)      
photo_transistor = ADC(Pin(26))      

i2c = I2C(0, scl=Pin(5), sda=Pin(4))
oled = SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c)   

sampling_interval = 0.1

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(sampling_interval)
        off_value = photo_transistor.read_u16()
        ir_led.on()
        time.sleep(sampling_interval)
        on_value = photo_transistor.read_u16()
        print(f"ON: {on_value}, OFF: {off_value}")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    red_led.off()
    ir_led.off()
    print("Data collection stopped.")

The data on the ADC pin connected with the phototransistor is constantly around 65k (when I tried using pull-up resistor) or around 600 (when using pull-down resistor.)
Nothing seems to affect the phototransistor reading - decreasing light in the room, placing the finger between LED&IR LED and the phototransistor. The phototransistor seems to just not read the data. I tried changing the phototransistor to a different one, and the photodiode but it never shows anything. The components that I am using are:

Raspberry Pi Pico H
SFH 313 FA phototransistor
SFH 203 IR diode

I think the OLED and red diode are irrelevant since they work.
I have tried many things, so I might just tell you now:

The current on LED and IR is around 15mA.
All of the wires are connected correctly.
The polarity of diodes is correct, and the phototransistor is connected with emitter to ground, and collector to ADC pin which is connected through a pull-up resistor to 3.3V provided by the Raspberry.
I have tried pull-down resistor, and the phototransistor reading doesn't change (except it's just 0V on the ADC pin constantly.)
I tried looking for a solution everywhere, but according to what I've found my circuit should work.
I don't know what else should I try.

EDIT: I have tried changing the value of the pull-up resistor to a higher value, but it also doesn't change anything. When I measure the current going through the phototransistor it's 0.
EDIT2: SOLUTION - it seems that there were 2 problems in my circuit. First one was that I mistakenly considered SFH 203 photodiode to be an IR LED, because the vendor that I bought it from said so, and I didn't think about checking the documentation. The phototransistor still didn't provide any reading when alternating between IR being ON and OFF, but when I disconnected the pull-up resistor entirely, the problem was fixed. Now I can see a difference between IR diode being ON and OFF, and a significant difference when I try the circuit with my room lights ON and OFF, so I guess the pull-up resistor was a problem all along.

do the LEDs light up?

@jsotola yes, the red LED lights up. I don't have the camera to check the IR LED though, but since it's new I'd assume it should work

Can whatever program you used to draw the wiring diagram alsop produce a proper circuit schematic diagram?

@JRE I drew a circuit in Cirkit Designer, but there is no simulations option that I know of

is the phototransistor connected correctly?

@jsotola yes, the collector of phototransistor is connected to GP26, and the emitter is connected to the ground (GP26 is also connected through pull-up 10kOhm resistor to 3.3V). Connecting to AGND pin and to normal GND doesn't make the difference - there is no reading.

I didn't ask for a simulation.  I asked for a schematic diagram.  Cirkit Designer apparently can't produce schematic diagrams. I won't be drawing a schematic from your wiring diagram, so that's the end of it for me.

At the end of the while loop you must call ir_led.off() or your next off_value is in fact an on_value.

I suspect you will have a hard time measuring SpO2 with phototransistors. The signal-to-background ratio is pretty small for pulse oximeters. I suggest using a photodiode with a bandpass filter and a high-gain trans-impedance amplifier. I would also sample more frequently and co-add the samples if possible.

The SFH 203 IR diode you list is a photodiode, not an LED. It's meant to be used as a sensor, similar to the SFH-313-FA phototransistor you are using. I'm not sure what should happen if you try to use it like an LED, it might emit light at some wavelength in the IR range, but it might not be very much as it's optimized for sensing IR, not emitting it.
So you've got two photosensors and no emitter, try changing out the diode with an IR LED.

Thank you so much, that is true. I don't know how I missed it. I've read the documentation of both SFH 203 and SFH 203 FA and I must've switched them but you are correct. I just assumed that photodiode is black and IR LED is white. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

@macius_o All of the SFH 203 series are sensors, I think the difference between the 203 and 203 FA is that the FA has a filtering lens (hence the dark color) to limit it's wavelength to 750nm-1100nm where the clear lens version is 400nm-1100nm. The SFH 313 FA phototransistor should also have the dark filtering lens.

I don't know that the question even listed the part numbers for the two emitters.  For certain the red LED is not in the parts list.  And the question talks about swapping between phototransistor and diode.... so that seems like both were being used as sensors, in alternate versions of the circuit.

@BenVoigt I'm pretty sure they were trying to use the photodiode as an LED, they even agreed in the first comment above. The red LED may not work well with the phototransistor as it's wavelength is filtered out by the phototransistor's lens. Hopefully they'll report back if using a real IR LED solves the problem.

I have ordered an IR LED, it should come tomorrow so I'll see if it works then. I didn't list the red diode since a) I don't know it's part number, and b) I was sure it works, so I didn't think the problem lies there.

Also, the swapping between phototransistor and photodiode that I mentioned was about a different photodiode, not SFH 203 that I wrongly thought was an IR LED. I don't know the part number of said photodiode, so I didn't mention it.

@GodJihyo I have tried a real IR LED now, and it seems to be working. I can see it in my phone's camera as suggested by another comment. But the phototransistor reading doesn't change. Although when I measure the phototransistor voltage between collector and emitter, it seems to change between 0 and around 200uV depending on the IR diode, although my multimeter doesn't measure any current. I suspected that the current is too low, and tried connecting BC547 transistor to use it as an amplifier, but there is no change. ADC0 pin shows 3.3V at all times.

The connection that I made was phototransistor collector - 10k resistor - BC547 base, BC547 emitter to the ground, and BC547 collector to both ADC0, and through 1k resistor to 3.3V. I'm not sure if I understand how transistor amplifier works, but the result didn't help, so either I'm doing something wrong, or this BC547 just doesn't work in this case

I think that I found a solution to my problem - turns out that disconnecting the pull-up resistor entirely provides much better results. I can actually see different results for an IR LED being turned on and off, as well as different results for visible light. I am not sure if disconnecting the pull-up resistor is a good idea, but that's finally something that works at least. Thank you for help, I will try to write some code that will turn the results into a BPM and SpO2 measurement

Since the camera of a cell phone is sensitive enough to verify that the IR LED is working, I strongly suggest doing that. Just open the camera app on your phone and hold the IR LED into the camera. If it lights up, you should see it as as purple light. If you do not have a camera at all, at least verify with a multimeter that there is the appropriate amount of current flowing through the IR LED.

I don't see anything in my phone's camera when the IR LED is working. I have changed the IR diode, and changed the current limiting resistor to 330Ohm and I measured 9.7mA going through the IR diode. My previous measurements with 100Ohm resistors were around 30mA

The back camera lenses have IR filters on them. The front-facing camera does not - try that.

The IR filter on the camera should not be strong enough to block all the IR light from the IR LED. You should see something if the IR LED is pointed directly into the camera in close proximity. Just to be sure, try the front-facing camera as someone else suggested. That said, if you see absolutely nothing from the IR LED through the camera, odds are that the LED is not emitting any IR light.

Required:

Narrow beam LED  https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/ams-osram-usa-inc/SFH-4550/806365  6 deg or similar
Narrow beam Daylight blocking IR PD  20 deg.  & a narrow beam RED LED
https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/AM2520PD1BT03.pdf or similar 940, 660 nm are essential.
TIA with variable high gain and null offset to Vref / 2.
Constant current LED driver with pulse enable and sequence generation
Bandpass filter to amplify pulses
servo loop first to null offset then maximize gain without clipping.
Offset is from diffused IR leakage bypassing arterial flow

Ref:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Bheema-Lingaiah/publication/365096662_Measurement_of_Pulse_rate_and_SPo2_using_Pulse_Oximeter_developed_using_LabVIEW/links/6364ac6d2f4bca7fd02dae18/Measurement-of-Pulse-rate-and-SPo2-using-Pulse-Oximeter-developed-using-LabVIEW.pdf&_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6Il9kaXJlY3QiLCJwYWdlIjoicHVibGljYXRpb24ifX0

https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/how-to-design-a-better-pulse-oximeter.html


Much more is required but these are my minimal guidelines.
Dual wavelength measurements are necessary to compute the ratio to extract Oxi content.

